# Search Products Not Found In Storefront GraphQL In Single Product

Tags: graphql, shopify, storefront

I am trying to get all product with search option but getting every time empty response.

I have a  2 store with below details

Store 1:  5 Categories ,  3 product on each category [ Total 15 product ]  (This Store Created  2 month ago)

store 2: 5 Categories ,  3 product on each category [ Total 15 product ]  (This store created yesterday )

Both store have a all same data with same type of property

I notice that newly created store i am not able to search product in storefront graphQL query

here i am adding my query also

URL : https://.myshopify.com/api/2023-07/graphql.json

JSON query:

```
{
products(first: 10 , sortKey: TITLE ,  query: "title:shirt" , reverse: true) {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      title
      description
      descriptionHtml
      handle
      productType
      vendor
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      publishedAt
      tags
      images(first: 1) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            src
            url
          }
        }
      }
      priceRange {
        maxVariantPrice {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        minVariantPrice {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
      }
      options(first: 100) {
        id
        name
        values
      }
      variants(first: 100) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            image {
              url
            }
            price{
              amount
              currencyCode
            }
            title
            availableForSale
            quantityAvailable
            selectedOptions {
              name
              value
            }
            product {
              id
              title
              updatedAt
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  pageInfo {
    hasNextPage
    hasPreviousPage
  }
}
}
```

output:

```
{
"data": {
    "products": {
        "edges": [],
        "pageInfo": {
            "hasNextPage": false,
            "hasPreviousPage": false
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You probably forgot to add your products to a sales channel. So when you do a query for them, you get nothing.

Comment: Hi @DavidLazar Thanks for comment,  as you said i see on each product and collection all the products are included on the sales channel